# What is best for node app with mongodb using docker container?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

What is best for node app with mongodb using docker container ?
Both node and mongodb in same docker container or having interlinked separate containers of nodeApp and mongodb ?

I have tried both approaches and both of them worked for me. For the first case I took ubuntu based image and installed node and mongodb using Dockerfile and started that container having both environments in same container. And for the second case, I used node and mongodb base-images and ran as separate containers. But confused which approach should I select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach of using both in separate containers provides you with multiple advantages,the first one is that you can scale them independently of each other.

In addition to that it will also allow you to use more lightweight images since they only require a very specific set of dependencies.

It will also allow you to create a more flexible environment for the future, i.e. if you ever want to add more containers which have a dependency on only one of these containers or the other way around you reduce the number of interactions between the components. If both were in the same container it would not be possible to allow another container only access to only MongoDB for example. Or if you expand your Node application let it only connect to another backend container instead of also having to couple that backend server with mongo.

**TLDR** use the approach with two separate containers, that is what docker is meant for and provides the most flexibility

Answer (score 1):

Considering scalability. It would be ideal using a separate container for both Node and MongoDB.

It gives you the flexibility. If you want to migrate only your MongoDB container to some other instance or server.